# html page cant be opened in raspberry Pi

Tags: python, html, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, geany

I'm making my first HTML page I have tried to do it on my computer and it loaded very fine, but when I do the same steps in my PI the HTML page won't load (i tried the simple HTML page provided by Geany (yes I'm doing all this in Geany) but still it keeps loading then it broke
I can load any other page for example Google, or Twitter...just fine.
as you can see it's not because of the code but of the PI itself
is there a way to fix this?? or maybe something is damaged in my pi?
I do have Nginx and PHP installed and it worked just fine  if that's a problem

how i saved it: i created a folder in Documents templates then i wend to Geany i made a new file and saved it as index.html so it looked like this/home/pi/Documents/sayHello/templates/index.html and when i click on it as i go to the templates file it keep loading then it showed me "Page Unresponsive untitled " under it and "Exit page" "Wait"

the url to my page is file:///home/pi/Documents/sayHello/templates/index.html
(i'm using VNC from my computer)
I'm a beginner at this I would appreciate the help

fixed (kind of):
i opened with Dillo and it worked!! Dillo is a light web browser on the Raspberry Pi
i still dont know what's the problem with chromium but im glad it worked on a Dillo browser at least

Comment: How are you opening it exactly?

Comment: Have you checked the server logs for error messages?

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan since I'm using VNC I go to the specific file and open it with the chromium browser

Comment: @Barmar not sure exactly what's the problem so i didn't know how to explain more..

Comment: @Barmar it showed me page Unresponsive with Exit page Wait

Comment: Please include how you saved your html page on to the PI.  How are you running your html page on your PI?  What does the browser say when you try to load the page.  What is the URL to your page?

Comment: That message usually means that the JavaScript in the web page is in an infinite loop. Which means that you did successfully download the page from the server, it just has a JS bug. Use the JavaScript debugger in the browser.

Comment: @ewong how i saved it: i created a folder in Documents templates then i wend to Geany i made a new file and saved it as index.html so it looked like this/home/pi/Documents/sayHello/templates/index.html and when i click on it as i go to the templates file it keep loading then it showed me "Page Unresponsive untitled " under it and "Exit page" "Wait" the url to my page is file:///home/pi/Documents/sayHello/templates/index.html

Comment: @tessaBrock  Please include that information in your post.

Comment: @Barmar sorry to ask since i'm new to this how do i use JavaScript debugger in the browser?

Comment: @ewong i did include the informations thank you

Comment: [The Beginner's Guide to Chrome Developer Tools](https://nira.com/chrome-developer-tools/)

Comment: Where are you trying to access this html page?  From your computer or on the PI?

Comment: @ewong, through another computer with VNC

Comment: @ewong yes im using VNC on another computer

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan  thanks.  Missed that comment.  Please include your code.

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan I did :) thank you for pointing it out

Comment: @Barmar I opened developer Tools with keyboard shortcuts through the Chromeuim on the ondex.html page and it didn't show me the HTML of the page on Elements...everything is empty